# Android WebView single image, remove white space on the right

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I have tried\applied all the suggestions from StackOverflow...to no avail.  What am I missing ?  Thank you.

[image]

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     String imagePath = "file:///android_asset/menu.jpg";
     webView.loadData("<html><style type='text/css'>img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;} div,p,span,a {max-width: 100%;}</style><body style='margin: 0; padding: 0'></html>","text/html", "utf-8");
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");

     webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

     webView.setInitialScale(1);
     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
     webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
     webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
     webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
     webView.loadUrl(imagePath);
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/sendblank" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Web"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />




      <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button03"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sendblank"
        android:onClick="onHome"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:typeface="serif" />


 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"    
        android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="45dp">

      <WebView android:id="@+id/webView1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tV1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
</TextView>

<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/pB1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:padding="2dip">
</ProgressBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Many Thanks....I honestly believe I have tried all the suggestions so I am not sure why it is not working in my case?  Have I applied the suggestions in the wrong way or place ???
-Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you're loading some html with style information, but no actual content in the `webView.loadData` call. But then you're completely replacing that html by loading an image url with the `webView.loadUrl` call.

If you want to load an image with styling you need to create the markup with an `img` tag pointing to your image url.  Then you can load that markup with the `webView.loadData` call.

Also, looking at your markup, that CSS wouldn't work as intended even if you had included the image. You've set the `max-width` of the image to 100%, which means it won't ever be wider than 100%, but that doesn't mean it won't be narrower. If you want the image to always fill the width of the screen, you should set the `width` property to 100%.

In addition, that markup is missing a closing body tag, and the style element should really be enclosed in a head tag. The browser won't mind, but you shouldn't make a habit of using bad markup, because it can end up having unexpected behaviour.

Finally, there's a whole bunch of styling there for other elements that appears to serve no purpose, since those elements don't exist.

So correcting all of the above, your code might look something like this:

```
String imagePath = "file:///android_asset/menu.jpg";
String markup = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>img {width: 100%%;}</style></head><body style='margin: 0; padding: 0'><img src='%s' /></body></html>";
markup = String.format(markup, imagePath);
try {
  markup = URLEncoder.encode(markup,"utf-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
} 
markup = markup.replace('+',' ');
webView.loadData(markup, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: The conversion error is probably the percent in the 100% that needs to be escaped. I'll update the answer along with the other problem you spotted.

Comment: Ah, we might also need to encode the markup first. Try adding `markup = URLEncoder.encode(markup);` before the `webView.loadData` call.

Comment: Now I get a blank white screen with "img+{width:+100%;}" in the top left corner ???  After adding    try {
   markup = URLEncoder.encode(markup,"utf-8");
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     webView.loadData(markup, "text/html", "utf-8");

Comment: Ok, that's the encode converting all the spaces into plusses. An additional line after the URLEncoder call should help. `markup = markup.replaceAll("\\+"," ");` Sorry, this is taking so long to get working. Although `markup = markup.replace('+',' ');` would probably be more effecient if it works.

Comment: Halleluiah !!!!   Solved May you live long and prosper !!!!  Many thanks James....it's working !!!!  I was honestly going crazy !!! thanks for all you're patience.

Comment: You're welcome. Again I'm sorry it took so long. If you can upvote my answer as well, I would appreciate that.